# simple & compact code for compressing DNA-like strings

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, compression

my app is multiple choice test, where for each question the response results in a 4 letter string "eg" GTAC or ATGC or CATG, etc.   There are always just 24 questions.  so the final result is something like

GTAC CATG TACG GACT GTAC CATG TACG GACT GTAC CATG TACG GACT GTAC CATG TACG GACT GTAC CATG TACG GACT GTAC CATG TACG GACT

so there are 4!=24 possibilities for each response.  I could map each possibility to a letter A-X and that would cut it down to a string of size of 24 letters, but I believe there must be a simple way to get it down to about 6 characters.

The results will be sent via http request so I need it compressed as an alphanumeric string, like base64 but not necessarily base64.

The data is just a string like above, or I can put it in whatever format to match your loop.  I'm looking for something like a 10 line compression algorithm. I will compress in javascript and uncompress in php.

Comment: Base64 will inflate your data. No cause for it when your data is in the domain of [A,T,G,C,]

Comment: @mccainz yes, I understand that.  I mean we can compress it into an alphanumeric string, and base64 is a good starting point for 64 legal characters

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I agree.. I think that his mapping of 4 code sequences to A-X would be sufficient.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  it's not just to compress it for the http trip. Results for thousands of people will be stored in a database.

Comment: @mcainz, I think the 96 Bytes they have now is sufficient, but 24 would be an improvement.

Comment: @mccainz 24*3=72, so if there is a base72 scheme, I can store 3 responses in one letter, making a 96 character string into 8 characters.  that's basically what I'm looking for

Comment: Stats is not my strong suit by any means but dont you have to account for 4*4*4*4 possibilities per response (AAAA,AAAC,AAAG etc...) ?

Comment: @mccainz  there are no repeating sequences. it is combinatorial, meaning they are changing the order of the 4 letters only.  So it's 4*3*2*1

Comment: @GenericHolidayName I'm sure the DB can handle it. But if theres a simple "loop" for cutting out 90% of the "data", I want to use it.  I guess it's like minifying your javascript, whereas the page will load fine if you don't.

Comment: Also, you are most likely not going to get very good compression on a string that small, and in many cases (with a 24 character string) compression algorithms may result in a larger string then what you started with.  For investigation https://code.google.com/p/jslzjb/

Comment: @mccainz I'm fully aware of issues with general compression algorithms on small data.  In this case, if you tried an algorithm that looked for repeating responses, such as GTAC GTAC GTAC and tried to compress that, with only 24 it would surely not work.  But clearly we don't need 4 bytes of data to store less than 4 bits of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum you can get it down to is 24 lg(24) ~= 111 bits or 14 bytes.  To then encode that to the 84 URL acceptable characters, you would have to expand it to at least 18 characters.  24 lg(24) / lg(84) = 17.2.  Assuming that all 24 choices are possible for each of the 24 answers, then there is no way to get it to less than 18 characters.  Certainly not six.

Your scheme of coding it in 24 characters seems fine to me.  The gain of 18 over 24 doesn't seem worth any additional complexity.  However, if you must ...

Split the answers into eight groups of three.  For each group of three, consider it to be a three-digit base 24 number, which will have a range of 0..13823.  That will fit in 14 bits.  Eight of those is then 14 bytes or 112 bits.

Now pull off 19 bits at a time.  There will be six sets, with the last set having only 17 bits.  For each set of 19, encode it as a three-digit base 81 number, emitting three URL-safe characters.  81<sup>3</sup> > 2<sup>19</sup>.  Pick whatever 81 characters out of the 84 URL-safe characters you like best.

Now you have 18 characters representing the 24 answers.  You can't do any better than that unless there are some other constraints on the answers that you haven't told us.

Comment: the groups of 3 and 14 bits is exactly what I came up with too.  And I posted a similar thing over on code golf and the result was 18 characters, though it just used 64 characters.   I'll probably just stick to the 24 letters, which will work better for machine learning clustering anyways.

Comment: It's not possible with just 64 characters.

Comment: check out this. it's the code golf where the guy comes out with 18 chars using 64: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15831/compressing-a-dna-like-string

Comment: I don't need to look at the code.  18 characters from a set of 64 can't code all possible inputs, since there are more possible inputs than that.  64^18 is less than one fourth of 24^24.  These are not difficult calculations.

Comment: But couldn't you say that about ANY lossless compression algorithm?  like bmp vs png. I understand png uses an entirely different idea, but maybe there are some non runlength algorithms that do something similar. The guy calls it bijective numeration

Comment: Yes, you can.  That same counting argument is _exactly_ why it is impossible for a lossless compression algorithm to compress all possible inputs.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing, It doesn't matter _how_ you enumerate them. You need at least 24^24 values in the output space. 64^18 isn't big enough. No matter how you'd "decompress" them they can only map back to 64^18 out of the 24^24 inputs.

Comment: That answer on codegolf only gives 18 as a particular result for the question's single example input -- it does not claim that *all* inputs result in an 18-character string. Sheesh.

Comment: Then they should calculate the average length of the output to see if it's a good approach.

Comment: @MarkAdler r.e.s. did a million random inputs and all the outputs were either 18 or 19, with an average of 18.8.  Just FYI.

Comment: @MarkAdler I bet you read about black holes in your spare time and try to calculate how much information can be contained in an electron. ;) This has been fun.